# Inno - prevent registry keys being redirected to the Wow6432Node

Tags: windows, registry, inno-setup

In my Inno installer I am writing some registry keys:

```
RegWriteStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.mycompany.myapp', '', ExpandConstant('{app}\{#MyAppChrome}'));
RegWriteStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Mozilla\NativeMessagingHosts\com.mycompany.myapp', '', ExpandConstant('{app}\{#MyAppChrome}'));
```

It automatically writes it to the keys under Wow6432Node, which is fine. But firefox expects it not be under Wow6432Node:

> Windows
>
> For global visibility, create a registry key with the following name:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\NativeMessagingHosts\ The
>   key should have a single default value, which is the path to the
>   manifest.
>
> Note that this key should not be created under Wow6432Node, even if
>   the app is 32-bit. The browser will always look for the key under the
>   "native" view of the registry, not the 32-bit emulation. To ensure
>   that the key is created in the "native" view, you can pass the
>   KEY_WOW64_64KEY or KEY_WOW64_32KEY flags into RegCreateKeyEx. See
>   Accessing an Alternate Registry View.

So, how can I prevent the redirection of firefox related registry key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install a 64-bit application on 64-bit Windows then you can change everything to 64-bit mode:

```
[Setup]
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
```

If you install a 32-bit application on 64-bit Windows then you can perform a specific write to the 64-bit registry view with a HK*64 registry root:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM64; Subkey: "Software\..."; ValueType: String; ValueData: "{app}..."; Flags: uninsdeletekey; Check: IsWin64
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\..."; ValueType: String; ValueData: "{app}..."; Flags: uninsdeletekey; Check: not IsWin64
```

You can also use `if IsWin64 then ...` if you prefer Pascal scripting.